# How can I find the max degree of concurrency and the critical path of task dependency graph?

Tags: parallel-computing

I study Parallel Processing,
and I get stuck into how to calculate the maximum degree of concurrency for task dependency graph.

I know that the max degree of concurrency is the largest number of concurrent tasks, and I have to calculate the sum of their weights, but in this graph, there are no weights and no fixed number of nodes.

can someone explain how can I find the solution for the following graph?

Note: the numbers insides the nodes represent the levels, not the weights.

Thank you all

[image]

Comment: An excellent first step would be *to forget about formulas*. Think what *maximum degree of concurrency* means – it's the maximum number of jobs that can be executed concurrently during execution. Then try some small case, $n=1,2,3,4$, and see whether you can figure this out *without using any formulas*.

Comment: so for this figure, I can say the max degree of concurrency is "n"?

Comment: It sounds reasonable.

Comment: Thank you! can I ask you please, is the critical path length is "n" also? I want to be sure :(, and Thank you again!

Comment: You don’t need me to be sure. If you truly understand the material, you can be sure in the answer yourself.